# DataGridView.ColumnReordered

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview

I know that there is an event handler for "ColumnReordered" with a DataGrid control. Does anyone know if there is such an event handler for the DataGridView control?

Comment: [Related MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/b2b7b8ff-2a86-4fcb-b7b6-445025963a1d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataGridView.ColumnSortModeChanged I believe is what you want.

Comment: Hi Mitch, thanks for your answer. However, it is not what I'm looking for. ColumnSortModeChanged will only fire up when the ColumnSortMode setting is changed. I'm looking for an event handler that is called when a column in the DataGridView is moved around.

Comment: Ah sorry about that.  In that case, I think that ColumnDisplayIndexChanged might work.  I did a quick google and found this similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168115/datagridview-handle-column-reordering-event).